# Client-Server disconnections in Battlefield 4

Tags: pc, technical-issues, battlefield-4

A friend of mine and me are facing connectivity problems when we try to join BF4-servers on PC. My problem is, that I always need join and face connection error 3 to 5 times before I can finally join the server and play until my eyes hurt without technical problems. What is happening? I click on Join server, wait until I am the first in queue and can join, then the game opens and closes itself while in the black loading screen with the single loading symbol OR the map loading screen where you see those fancy pictures of the map. After the game closed itself, since the newest Winter 2015 update, I additionally get Windows-message that the program has stopped working. Finally, after I click away those message, I see the battlelog message on the red bottom, where it say that connection to the server could not be established.

My friend has a similar problem, though he does not face it so often like me. I face it really EVERY time I try to join a new server. He does face it like every second time. However, his problem is more critical, because since the newest update, his connection stops even in the middle of the game, and he can never play longer than 2-5 minute before game stops and he is in battlelog staring at those battlelog connection problem message.

Any ideas? I use Windows 8.1, I even tried to deactivate all firewalls and deactivated my antivirus software. NAT/PAT is activated and opened. Also, on my PC, there is only Steam and Origin installed with a few games, nothing else is installed. The following are my hardware specs, those of my friend are similar:

CPU: Intel Core i7-4790K 4,0 Ghz LGA 1150 | GPU: MSI AMD Radeon R9 280X 3GB DRR5 | RAM: G.Skill TridentX PC3-19200U CL10 16 GB | SSD: Samsung 840 EVO Basic 500 GB SATA 6 GB/s | PSU: be quiet! Pure Power L8 CM 630 Watt | MBU: ASRock Fatal1ty Z97 Killer LGA1150 ATX

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing Smart Port Forwarder and setting both TCP and UDP ports to port 3659

Since then, I have not experienced a single connection error. Do not forget to set up Smart Port Forwarder for AutoStart because currently it does not have any "launch on startup" options yet.

Answer (score -2):

You need to open some ports on your Router. Had this problem, too. Since then it works fine.

the ports:

PC:
TCP: 80, 443, 9988, 17502, 20000-20100, 22990, 42127 
UDP: 3659, 14000-14016, 22990-23006, 25200-25300

PS3:
TCP: 80, 443, 9988, 10000-10100, 17502, 42127 
UDP: 3659, 14000-14016

PS4:
TCP: 80, 443, 1935, 3478-3480
UDP: 3478-3479

XBOX 360:
TCP: 53, 88, 3074, 80
UDP: 53, 88, 3074

XBOX One: 
TCP: 53, 80, 3074 
UDP: 53, 88, 500, 3074, 3544, 4500

Comment: And which ports would that be?

Comment: So i got downvoted, because someone was too lazy to google: 

here is the link http://help.ea.com/de/article/online-ports-for-battlefield-4/

Comment: You're the one answering; the onus is on you to provide that information in your answer.  You need to put the ports themselves in your answer; not just a link to where to find them.  What happens to your answer if that page goes down?  Not really all that useful, is it?

Comment: then battlefield is down, too.